# update label.txt (live) when Vscroll bar is changing (vb2010)

Tags: vb.net

EDITED:

I want to make my question more simple

check the code

```
Public Class Form1 
        Dim v1 As Double  
    Dim v2 As Double   
    Dim v3 As Double  
         Private Sub Form1_Load(By Val sender As System.Object, By Val e As System.Eventuates) Handles My Base.Load
    label1.text=v1
label2.text=v2
label3.text=v3
     end sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(By Val sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Eventuates) Handles Button1.Click
        v1=v1+10
        v2=v2+20
        v3=v3+30
        End Sub
   end class
```

I want when push the button the label change directly in the form
how can I do that without load form in button sub ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand your problem but calling Form1_Load is weird and settling label2 to an uninitialized value is also weird. I would suggest you put all of the display logic in a method instead.

```
Private Sub DisplayScrollValue(ByVal scrollValue As Double)
    Label1.Text = scrollValue
    label2.text = scrollValue
End Sub

Private Sub VScrollBar1_Scroll(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventArgs) Handles VScrollBar1.Scroll

    DisplayScrollValue((VScrollBar1.Value * -1 / 10).ToString())

End Sub

Private Sub Form11_Load(By Val sender As System.Object, By Val e As System.Eventuates) Handles My Base.Load

    DisplayScrollValue(0)

end sub
```

I notice your edit and the solution is very similar to what I wrote. Just have a method that sets the labels and call it when you want to update them.

```
Public Class Form1 
    Dim v1 As Double  
    Dim v2 As Double   
    Dim v3 As Double  

    Private Sub UpdateLabels()
        label1.text=v1
        label2.text=v2
        label3.text=v3
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(By Val sender As System.Object, By Val e As System.Eventuates) Handles My Base.Load
        UpdateLabels()
    end sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(By Val sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Eventuates) Handles Button1.Click
        UpdateLabels()
    End Sub
end class
```

Comment: @hamza After reading your edit, what you need is very similar to what I already wrote.